# How to separate out basic search of splunk in two different columns?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am new to Splunk and facing an issue in separating out the two columns of the query. I tried with the below query and found the results as shown below in table1

```
...|
append 
    [ search index="pd" "successful" "notif/output/" 
    | stats count by _raw 
    | fields count 
    | rename _raw as Dtransfer] 
| 
append 
    [ search index="pd" "SBID=nr" "DM" "PAM=sende" "notif/archive/" 
    | stats count by _raw 
    | fields count 
    | rename _raw as DMCopy]
```

[image: table1]

How do I achieve the expected result shown in Table 2? I need to display two separate columns DtransferCount and DMCopyCount

[image: table2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the counts different names and they'll be in separate columns.

```
...
| append [search index="pd" "successful" "notif/output/"
  | stats count as DtransferCount by _raw 
  | fields DtransferCount 
  | rename _raw as Dtransfer] 
| append [search index="pd" "SBID=nr" "DM" "PAM=sende" "notif/archive/" 
  | stats count as DMCopyCount by _raw 
  | fields DMCopyCount
  | rename _raw as DMCopy]
```